# GIMP getting removed all of a sudden

Tags: 20.04, gimp

This happened twice and that's why I think that something is wrong.
After booting up my system, I search for GIMP on in the apps list, but it is not there. I open up the terminal and type `gimp`, but it says that `command gimp not found, install it with apt install gimp`. Then, I need to install GIMP once more and it installs normally. All the other apps are there as usual, only GIMP goes missing.
Another thing I noticed, after I reinstall GIMP, it retains my previous preferences!
What has been going wrong?

Comment: The user preferences are in the Gimp profile and this stays around even if you explicitly uninstall Gimp, so the next install finds it and reuses it. `/usr/bin/gimp` is a link to `/usr/bin/gimp-2.10` so is that one gone too? And do yiu also lose `/usr/{lib,share}/gimp`?

Comment: Yes, it got removed. I think this had happened because Iby mistake I had removed some libraries on which GIMP depends on. This had also happened with Kdenlive after I had removed all KDE-based libraries.